# How to get the angle of a line?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects

I am new to ArcObjects, I need to identify the angle of the line in a particular Layer "MV Feeder"

I am trying the below code, which gives error "object reference is not set to and instance of the objects":

```c#
 public void ShowLineAngle()
    {
        IMxDocument mxdoc = ArcMap.Application.Document as IMxDocument;
        IMap map = mxdoc.FocusMap;
        if (map.Layer[0] == null)
        { return; }

        for (int i = 0; i < map.LayerCount; i++)
            {
                if (map.Layer[i].Name == "MV Feeder")
                {
                    ILayer HTOverheadLine = map.Layer[i];

                    IFeatureLayer fl1 = new FeatureLayerClass();
                    fl1 = HTOverheadLine as IFeatureLayer;
                    ILine line = new LineClass();
                    IQueryFilter qF = new QueryFilterClass();
                    qF.WhereClause = "";
                    IFeatureCursor featureCursor = fl1.Search(qF, false);
                    IFeature feature = null;
                    while ((feature = featureCursor.NextFeature()) != null)
                    {
                        line = feature.Shape as ILine;
                        double angle = line.Angle;
                        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Angle = " + angle);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: line = feature.Shape as ILine;

Comment: Try adding the shape field name to the queryfilter subfields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An your features' shape shouldn't be an ILine (a two point line), it's most likely an [IPolyLine](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m000002p0000000) (lots of two point lines).

But for the basics..

- you don't need a QueryFilter if you want to cursor through all your features so creating your
  [IFeatureCursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0025000002vs000000) from your [FeatureLayer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0012000004tp000000) goes like `IFeatureCursor
  featureCursor = fl1.Search(null, false);`
- I don't recommend you call [IFeature.Shape](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002500000330000000), instead use [IFeature.ShapeCopy](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/ShapeCopy_Property/002500000331000000/), unintended ramifications can occur if you reference the shape directly.
- Your FeatureClass would be a PolyLine (or Polygon, it matters little) feature class which is a geometry collection made from [point collection](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m00000275000000)(s) as [paths](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m0000026n000000) or [rings](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m00000356000000), you need to reference each part and then each point - or in this case [ISegment](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m0000035q000000) from [ISegmentCollection](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m00000369000000). ISegment implements ILine so can be cast from this.
- The [Angle](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m0000022n000000) of the line (each segment) is *The angle between this line and the positive x-axis* which isn't very useful to my mind, perhaps what you're after is more of a 3-point-angle using [IConstructAngle.ConstructThreePoint](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m000000qs000000) to find the interior angle at the 2nd point.
- It's a good idea to check that a [layer is Valid](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//001200000770000000) before trying to cast to an IFeatureLayer. A layer is valid if the feature source is found and invalid when not set (red exclamation mark in ArcMap).
- I know you can cast an ILine directly from a polyline but it's not clear which angle is being measured, is it the first segement? FisrtPoint-LastPoint? What about multipart lines? If you want the overall first vertex to last vertex then construct your line from two points.

To generate a two point line (ILine) from the first and last vertex of the first part of a polyline:

```
ILine myLine = new LineClass();
IPointCollection FirstPart = pGeomColl.get_Geometry(0);
myLine.PutCoords(FirstPart.get_Point(0), FirstPart.get_Point(FirstPart.PointCount - 1));
```

Your code edited to drill down to the part/segment level:

```
public void ShowLineAngle()
{
  IMxDocument mxdoc = ArcMap.Application.Document as IMxDocument;
  IMap map = mxdoc.FocusMap;
  if (map.Layer[0] == null)
  { return; }

  for (int i = 0; i < map.LayerCount; i++)
  {
    if (map.Layer[i].Valid) // make sure the layer is valid first
    {
      if (map.Layer[i].Name == "MV Feeder")
      {
        ILayer HTOverheadLine = map.Layer[i]; // a bit redundant
        IFeatureLayer fl1 = HTOverheadLine as IFeatureLayer;
        ILine line;
        IFeatureCursor featureCursor = fl1.Search(null, false);
        IFeature feature;

        while ((feature = featureCursor.NextFeature()) != null)
        {
          if (feature.Shape != null)
          {
            IGeometryCollection pGeomColl = (IGeometryCollection)feature.ShapeCopy;
            for (int ThisPart = 0; ThisPart < pGeomColl.GeometryCount; ThisPart++)
            {
              ISegmentCollection pSegColl = (ISegmentCollection)pGeomColl.get_Geometry(ThisPart);
              for (int ThisSeg = 0; ThisSeg < pSegColl.SegmentCount; ThisSeg++)
              {
                line = (ILine)pSegColl.get_Segment(ThisSeg);
                double angle = line.Angle;
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Angle = " + angle); // this will happen *a lot*
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: it is working but the angle it is returning i could not understand. i created a line at 25 degree, this returns 0.4363... , which format of angle this is ?

Comment: i got it , it is radian , need to convert it through "angle * (180.0 / Math.PI)", thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

As @Hornbydd suggested, it looks like your feature isn't returning a geometry (shape may be null). Try setting the subfields property to the shapefieldname property of the featureclass you are querying.

```
IQueryfilter qF = new QueryFilterClass();
qF.WhereClause = "";
qF.SubFields = fl1.FeatureClass.ShapeFieldName
```

Might also be worth checking that your geometry type is actually a line before attempting to cast to a line object, can never be too careful!

```
if (fl1.FeatureClass.ShapeType != esriGeometryType.esriGeometryLine)
{
  throw new Exception("Invalid geometry type.");
}
```

Comment: Good idea on testing geometry type!